# Unable to connect to ejabberd server using smack api

Tags: ejabberd, smack

I am trying to connect to the ejabberd server and using Smack Api. Below is the code for connection to server. After setting username, Host, and localhost Service, i am trying to show a Toast whenever it is connected. On debugging, neither Toast is shown nor any exception... please have a look at code below

```
       XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setUsernameAndPassword("alien@localhost", "alien")
                .setServiceName("localhost")
                .setHost("192.168.1.xx")
                .setPort(5222)
                         .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .build();

        AbstractXMPPConnection conn2 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        try {
            conn2.connect();
            conn2.login();
            if(conn2.isConnected())
           {
    Toast.makeText(ChatClient.this,"isConnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
   else
     {
        Toast.makeText(ChatClient.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

Following are dependencies which i have used in my project,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0"
    // Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"
    // Optional for XMPP-IM (RFC 6121) support (Roster, Threaded Chats, …)
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0"
    // Optional for XMPP extensions support

    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0"
}
```

My domain is ( 192.168.***.2*:5280/admin )..thank you in advance :)

Comment: What's your issue ? What are the error on your Android client side in debug mode ? Please give more info.

Comment: it does not show any error neither any sort of exception ..perhaps that is the only issue i have with this...and  im not getting rid of this issue